# VBA searching by date in access function

Tags: sql, vba, syntax-error, ms-access-2010

Can someone help me with my code below. I am trying to promt the user for a date, then search by that date in the table. The table I am querying has the datetime format, but I want to be able to search just by the date. 
I am able to get the user input but then I get the error "syntax error (missing operator) in query expression.

```
 Function cmdInputBox_Click()
    Dim DatePick As Date
    DatePick = InputBox("Enter Date:", "Date", Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yy"))

  Dim strSQL As String


    strSQL = " INSERT INTO PalletMoves " _
        & "SELECT [Pick Area].[From Location], [Pick Area].[Game Number], [Pick Area].[Pallet Number], [Pick Area].[Game Name], [Pick Area].[Shipment Number], [Pick Area].[Box Range], [Pick Area].Cases, [Pick Area].Packs, [Pick Area].Tickets, [Pick Area].[Price Point], [Pick Area].[Delivery Date], [Pick Area].Skids, [Pick Area].[Created Date] " _
        & "FROM [Pick Area] " _
        & "WHERE CAST([Created Date] AS Date) dateDate = '" & DatePick & "';"
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL

End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

A where clause have to look like:

```
"WHERE [Created Date] = #" & DatePick & "#;"
```

More at: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Examples-of-using-dates-as-criteria-in-Access-queries-aea83b3b-46eb-43dd-8689-5fc961f21762

Note: i need to warn you. When user remove default string and click `Cancel` button, `InputBox` function will return empty string! You should check it before you execute further code (query).

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I made the change, however i still need to enter the exact value date and time for example 4/4/2015 5:13:47 PM when searching or it won't return any results. How can I write it so that all I would need to enter is 4/4/2015? Thank you

Comment: So... why do you convert date to its short form (only date)?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure if I'm being clear... I'd like to search by the short date, but now it only works if I search by the date and time. I think my conversion is not working.

Comment: Oh... Try to convert it as: `WHERE CDate(Format([Created date], "MM/dd/yyyy))= #" & DatePick & "#;"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the Date value inside `#` while using it as a criteria in MS Access Queries.

```
strSQL = " INSERT INTO PalletMoves " _
        & "SELECT [Pick Area].[From Location], [Pick Area].[Game Number], [Pick Area].[Pallet Number], [Pick Area].[Game Name], [Pick Area].[Shipment Number], [Pick Area].[Box Range], [Pick Area].Cases, [Pick Area].Packs, [Pick Area].Tickets, [Pick Area].[Price Point], [Pick Area].[Delivery Date], [Pick Area].Skids, [Pick Area].[Created Date] " _
        & "FROM [Pick Area] " _
        & "WHERE [Created Date] = #" & DatePick & "#;"
```

More to read here : https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Examples-of-using-dates-as-criteria-in-Access-queries-aea83b3b-46eb-43dd-8689-5fc961f21762